# Significato di "al pelo" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> A me invece andava tutto **al pelo**: era tanta la forza e la gioventú e l’allegria in me che adesso rendevo il doppio sul lavoro e Tobia si lasciò prender dall’onta e mi fissò un premio di tre scudi, a darmeli dopo i raccolti. Cosí potevo fare un po’ piú bella figura e dare qualche soddisfazione a Fede; come quella volta che la portai a Cappelletto a veder la lanterna magica di quell’uomo di Roddino, e per due soldi a testa ci vedemmo la caccia alla volpe e la donna che faceva correre suo marito con la scopa.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "al pelo" in questo passaggio? Nel  [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/al-pelo) ho trovato questa definizione della locuzione "al pelo"

> all’ultimo momento: ho preso il treno al pelo

ma non sembra avere senso in questo contesto.

Comment: A orecchio direi che significa “andava tutto bene” (che non è lo stesso di prendere il treno per un pelo/al pelo, cioè all'ultimo momento).

Comment: Sono d'accordo sul significato, è la stessa cosa che dire "andava tutto per il verso giusto" ma "pelo" nel senso di "all'ultimo momento" non c'entra nulla. In questo caso secondo me il modo di dire significa che la sua vita lo stava accarezzando dal verso giusto, piacevole, gradito (quello del pelo appunto) mentre "contropelo" significa al contrario una cosa fastidiosa e indesiderata (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/contropelo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trovi il significato su Treccani nella definizione di [pelo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pelo/):

> 5.b. Poco com. le locuz. avv. *a pelo*, precisamente, in modo esatto, a
>   pennello (*tutto va a pelo*).

Il significato nel contesto da te citato è che tutto stava andando per il verso giusto, a meraviglia.